# D3js applying drop shadow on mouseover

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/3787476) (see preview [here](http://bl.ocks.org/3787476)) about potential way of applying filter.
I am not sure how to apply it conditionally on rect on which mouseover triggered. The example I see so far is applying a filter id, but if I change the filter property as in the above example, it affect all the element.

I am infact looking for box shadow to indicate a selection (as [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/arrow-with-dropshadow.svg))
If you can change blur to shadow, that would be great.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to apply the filter property with a CSS :hover rule instead, see [this example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/interactivity/transparent-images-pointer-events.svg).

Define your blur filter similar to what you've already done, then use a CSS like this:

```
rect:hover { filter: url(#blur); }
```

You should probably specify a slightly larger filter region too, your blur will get clipped otherwise.